# set all months to a list in java

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to get all 12 months into a String list in java. How can I do this using the java.util calender.
I've used the following code to build a year list! now I want is to build a month list for the 12 months.

```
protected String getYears(){
        int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);

        int futureYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        List<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = -2 ; i < 1 ; i++){
            if(i != 0){
                cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.add(Calendar.YEAR,i);
                years.add(Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
            }else if(currentYear != futureYear){
                years.add(Integer.toString(currentYear));
                years.add(Integer.toString(futureYear));
            }else if(currentYear == futureYear){
                years.add(Integer.toString(currentYear));
            }
        }


        HTMLOptionBuilder ob = new HTMLOptionBuilder(false);
        for(int i = 0; i < years.size(); i++){
            if(years.get(i).equals(currentYear)){
                ob.addOption(years.get(i), years.get(i), true, true);
            }else{
                ob.addOption(years.get(i), years.get(i));
            }
        }
        return ob.getHTML();
    }
```

please help me!
thank you!

Comment: I cannot use another plugin! I'm asking for java util!

Comment: Your description and your code do not seem to match. What is all this future year stuff? [do you want this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale%29)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<String> monthsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
    for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
      String month = months[i];
      System.out.println("month = " + month);
      monthsList .add(months[i]);
    }
```

[**DateFormatSymbols**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html)

Comment: Or probably [this](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/63.html) ?

Answer (score 7):

This uses 100 less characters than PSR's solution. :)

```
List<String> months = Arrays.asList("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
```

Also I think this is more immediately obvious, but doesn't work if you want locales or other weird things.

Answer (score 6):

[`Calendar.getDisplayNames(int field, int style, Locale locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayNames%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale%29) gives you a `Map` of month names and their corresponding integer values.

e.g the following -

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Map<String, Integer> map = cal.getDisplayNames(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(map);
```

should display something as follows -

```
{October=9, January=0, April=3, February=1, August=7, June=5, November=10, July=6, May=4, December=11, March=2, September=8}
```

You can use the map to form the list as you like.

Note: This is just in case you should use something from `java.util`, although I like the one presented by [@PSR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16828201/738746) better, which seems to be the most straight forward (and also supports locale).

Answer (score 1):

```
     import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
     import java.util.Locale;

public class MonthNames {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
    for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
        String month = months[i];
        System.out.println("month = " + month);
    }

    String[] shortMonths = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
    for (int i = 0; i < shortMonths.length; i++) {
        String shortMonth = shortMonths[i];
        System.out.println("shortMonth = " + shortMonth);
    }

    String[] germanyMonths = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY).getMonths();
    for (int i = 0; i < germanyMonths.length; i++) {
        String germanyMonth = germanyMonths[i];
        System.out.println("germanyMonth = " + germanyMonth);
    }

    String[] germanyShortMonths = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY).getShortMonths();
    for (int i = 0; i < germanyShortMonths.length; i++) {
        String germanyShortMonth = germanyShortMonths[i];
        System.out.println("germanyShortMonth = " + germanyShortMonth);
    }
}
}
```

Reference [Get Months Example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/63.html)

Comment: What's odd about the getMonths() method is that it returns an array of length 13, with the last element being empty.  Is this a bug?